# display the language name of an lstlisting under the rule

Tags: listings, languages

I am writing code form different languages in one document. Because of that it would be nice, if it is possible to display the name of the language below the rule of an lstlisting.

This is my code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{
%   backgroundcolor=\color{},
    commentstyle=\color{green},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    stringstyle=\color{black!50!green},
    %        identifierstyle=\color{red},
    numbers=left,
    captionpos=t,
    showstringspaces=false,
    tabsize=2,
    frame=b,
    breaklines=true,
    xleftmargin=17pt,
    framexleftmargin=17pt,
}

\begin{document}


    Much text
    \begin{lstlisting}[language=C++]
#inlcude <iostream.h>

int end = 5;

for(int i = 0; i < end; i++)
{
    std::cout << "Hello world!";
}
    \end{lstlisting}

%This should happen automaticly
%----------------------------------------------------

 \begin{flushright}
    c++
 \end{flushright}

%----------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the package `etoolbox` you can hook to the `lstlisting` environment to store the language option in a macro. Then you can add code after the environment to display the `flushright` environment with the language.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\AtEndEnvironment{lstlisting}{\xdef\xlang{\lst@language}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{lstlisting}{\begin{flushright}\xlang\end{flushright}}
\makeatother

\lstset{
%   backgroundcolor=\color{},
    commentstyle=\color{green},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    stringstyle=\color{black!50!green},
    %        identifierstyle=\color{red},
    numbers=left,
    captionpos=t,
    showstringspaces=false,
    tabsize=2,
    frame=b,
    breaklines=true,
    xleftmargin=17pt,
    framexleftmargin=17pt,
}

\begin{document}


    Much text
    \begin{lstlisting}[language=C++]
#include <iostream.h>

int end = 5;

for(int i = 0; i < end; i++)
{
    std::cout << "Hello world!";
}
    \end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=bash]
echo "Hello world!"
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

For environments defined with `\lstnewenvironment` the idea is the same. The syntax is actually easier because `\lstnewenvironment` allows you to define what happens at the end of the environment in the third argument, so you can put the language name there instead of using `\AtEndEnvironment` and `\AfterEndEnvironment`. Note that you do need `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` around `\lstnewenvironment` because `\lst@language` contains an `@` symbol.

Relevant snippet (using the example `pascalx` environment from the listings manual):

```
\makeatletter
\lstnewenvironment{pascalx}[1][]
{\lstset{language=pascal,numbers=left,numberstyle=\tiny,#1}}
{\begin{flushright}\lst@language\end{flushright}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That is what I am looking for. Is it possible to reduce the distance between the environment and the language?

Comment: @Ahrtaler an easy workaround is to add some negative vertical space at the start of the environment: `\begin{flushright}\vspace{-5mm}\xlang\end{flushright}`

Comment: What should one do for a new environment from \lstnewenvironment{somename} ?

Comment: @QiTianluo it is basically the same, see edit.

Comment: @Marijn Thank you very much! So an additional question. Why not put the ``` \xdef ``` block also in the end section of the definition of new environment?

Comment: @QiTianluo good idea, I tested it and it works, so I edited it in. I first thought it would not work because `\lst@language` has local scope, but apparently the end definition of `\lstnewenvironment` is still within that scope.

Comment: @Marjin Good! Thank you very much!

Comment: This unfortunately does not work with `\lstinputlisting`